# How to add a onTouchEvent to application?

Tags: java, android, events, touch, screen

I create a very simple ping-pong application for android.

It seems pretty good, but I have one problem:

I try to perform a onScreenTouch event, in order to place the racket in the user's touch location.

My question is - where to add the `Obj.addOnTouchEvent(this)`?

What object handle the screen touch? what is the screen object?

Comment: How do you implement your graphic? If you are using SurfaceView/openGL, then set its onTouchEvent() yo your implementation

Comment: see this. http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/handle-ontouchevent-in-surfaceview.html

Answer (score 1):

Any graphic widget can handle the touch event. Normally the View or Activity are used for the case.

There are several ways to handle the touches, but I suggest the `GestureListener`:

```
public class GestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener 
{
    MyView appliedView; //view who responses to graphical gestures

    public GestureListener(MyView currentView) 
    {
        this.appliedView = currentView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
            float dx,
            float dy) {
        //make your view response to gestures
        appliedView.onGestureMove(e1, e2, dx, dy);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
            float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And in your View class:**

```
public class MyView extends View 
{
    private GestureDetector gestureMgr;

    public MyView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        gestureMgr= new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        return gestureMgr.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void onGestureMove(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dx, float dy)
    {
        //check obj is touched or not
        //do moving objects around              
    }
}
```